# Remover caracteres de um texto

Tags: delphi, editor-de-texto

Olá, preciso fazer uma aplicação que dentro de um bloco de notas (que eu fiz), remover dados em um intervalo. O que preciso agora e saber como remover o email (em parenteses) da frase.
Exemplo:

> De: João de Almeída <joao.almeida@dominio.com.br>
>   Para: João de Almeída

Alguém sabe com fazer ou dar alguma dica? 
Obs.: São vários nomes seguidos com email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isto que vc quer fazer!!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var p1, p2 : Integer; linha : String;
begin
   linha := 'De: João de Almeída <joao.almeida@dominio.com.br>';
   ShowMessage('Antes: '+ linha );
   p1 := pos('<', linha );
   p2 := pos('>', linha );
   Delete( linha, p1, p2);
  ShowMessage('Depois: '+ linha );
end;
```

Comment: obrigado mas ja consegui resolver :D

Comment: @Wederson , Favor colocar sua solução na sua pergunta em questão e analisar se a resposta se encaixa  como solução para seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Segue solução para o problema...

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.RemoverEmailJackson;
var
  vTexto: string;
  vTextoAux: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  try
    vTextoAux := TStringList.Create;
    vTexto := trim(Frmtexto.Memo1.Text);
    while length(vTexto) <> 0 do
    begin
      vTextoAux.Add(trim(Copy(vTexto, 0, pos('<', vTexto) - 1)));
      Delete(vTexto, 1, pos('>', vTexto) + 1);
    end;

    vTextoAux.Sort;
    Frmtexto.Memo1.Text := vTextoAux.Text;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vTextoAux);
  end;
end;
```